# Open file in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-sdcard, android-file

I am using the below code to browse and pick files from sd card.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

When user selects a file I am fetching its path using this line of code

```
String picturePath = data.getData().getPath();
```

But when I try to open this file using the below code I am getting file not found exception

```
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream( Uri.fromFile(new File(picturePath)));
```

I am getting this as the path to the selected file

```
/external/images/media/36
```

How can I do this in android?

Thanks

Comment: What version of android are you using to test?

Comment: There's something weird with that path, it's missing the file extension. It looks like you are selecting an image, so there should be a file extension.

Comment: @Marcelo That is a content provider URI. Nothing wrong with it, only the way he is trying to access it. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
```

Alternatively, if you want to use a File:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html

Be sure to use `getAbsolutePath()` instead of `getPath()`;

Comment: Hi Sorry :) . It works on some device but in older versions its still returning same as above. I am testing on android 2.2